# I can't see logs from new workflow - Alfresco SDK Maven

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I'm working with Alfresco Maven SDK, following the steps from here: https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html#introdu...

I chose the last version of SDK.

I have this in my new BPMN diagram:

```
<process id="helloWorld" name="Hello World" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="sid-4e762918-2c74-4b5d-a951-5c8623f76885" name="Start" activiti:formKey="scwf:submitHelloWorldTask"/>
    <userTask id="sid-ffa0c4f2-08c5-4df3-8cea-d941311f80ad" name="Alfresco User Task" activiti:assignee="${initiator.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="wf:activitiReviewTask"/>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-e7d03eaa-4ce8-4056-8ec2-e17ca365240e" sourceRef="sid-4e762918-2c74-4b5d-a951-5c8623f76885" targetRef="sid-ffa0c4f2-08c5-4df3-8cea-d941311f80ad">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:executionListener event="start" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.listener.ScriptExecutionListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
             <activiti:string>logger.log("Hello, World!");</activiti:string>
           </activiti:field>
        </activiti:executionListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="sid-6cb74d1d-927f-45d8-96de-00b82a06982a"/>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-5831021d-ad0a-4ed0-8794-42b787fc5bde" sourceRef="sid-ffa0c4f2-08c5-4df3-8cea-d941311f80ad" targetRef="sid-6cb74d1d-927f-45d8-96de-00b82a06982a"/>
  </process>
```

And I don't see the log: `logger.log("Hello, World!");` when I start the workflow.

I already changed this value in dev-log4j.xml:

`log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger=DEBUG`

and others like:
`log4j.logger.org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptLogger=DEBUG`

Also tried to change to change
`logger.log("Hello, World!");`
for:
console.log or logger.debug

Thanks a lot!!